# Why am i getting compilation error in this pinescript.....?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

```
//@dztrctstar
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
coinToss = math.random(0, 1)
if (coinToss > 0.5)
    arrowSeries = 1
else
    arrowSeries = 0

shapeType = if arrowSeries == 1
    shape.arrowup
else
    shape.arrowdown


plotshape(
    shapeType,
    x = 0,
    y = arrowSeries,
    color = if arrowSeries == 1
        color.green
    else
        color.red

)
```

iam getting
11:46:06 AM — Compilation error. Line 16: Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

But if i remove complete code block in line 16 iam still getting errors in other if blocks can anyone tellme what should i do

I tried checking indentations and also changed other indentations but iam not getting any result

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a whole if statement inside `plotshape()`.

Either do that in the global scope and use the result to assign the color value, or use the [ternary operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Operators.html#ternary-operator).

Also, you are defining `arrowSeries` in a local block. Then use it later in an if statement which will not work. Because it won’t be visible there.